# Does Chrome handle empty form fields different to other browsers?

Tags: php, forms, google-chrome

According to a PHP script of mine, Google Chrome is sending an empty (e.g. no `value=""`) input field with a form post. This is reflected in `$_POST` superglobal in PHP. However, other browsers are not exhibiting this same behavior.

Furthermore, the `<input>` in question is inside of a `<div style="display: none;"/>` (that is verbatim in the code). It seems as if other browsers don't send this along.

How/where do I find documentation or proof that Chrome handles this differently?

**Update**

It turns out that the div has a css style applied to it which applies `visibility: hidden;` - I'm not sure if this alters the answers below or not.

See here for actual code:

*From the form-handler:*

```
    $check = stripslashes($form['E-mail']);
     if (!empty($check)) {
        $problem = false; 
        $errors[] = '0|wrong spamcheck code!';
        }
```

*From the form:*

```
  <td><div style="visibility:hidden; display:none"> <input type="text" name="E-mail" ></div></td>
```

Comment: Why does it matter? You should be validating the form values in your PHP anyway.

Comment: @jsumners if you add a hidden field as a honeypot for scripts/bots it will submit a value. again this should be validated, but it would cause problems

Comment: Do you have any chrome extensions? Can you post the HTML source?

Comment: I'm working on posting the source. @Greg - Yes, this is for a honeypot.

Comment: Would really like to see more source code, and your attempts to duplicate using similar code. You state the `input` is inside a div that ends with `/>`. This is impossible, since the div is closed with its own tag, you cannot put anything inside this div. What you are experiencing may be an artifact of bad code, and other browsers actually handling it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution - it turns out that in Chrome, it populates this form field with your auto-complete email address. A `var-dump` of the results of the form submission confirmed.

Thanks so much to those who looked into this - it led me down the path to solution. Votes up for all!

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that **both** Firefox and Safari exhibit this behaviour too.

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenField" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The results of this are:

```
array(1) {
  ["hiddenField"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Also tested inside a hidden div, and with `value=""`, result was the same. Should also point out, I don't think closing a div with `/>` is actually allowed according to standards, seems like bad practice to me regardless (since you state it is verbatim).

Edit: Out of my own curiosity, I have now also tried it without `type="hidden"` (`type` attribute removed completely, simple `<div style="display:none"><input name="hiddenField" /></div>`) and placing it inside a div with `display: none`. Results remained consistant in Firefox and Safari.

Comment: Whatever the case may be, I'm just debugging an existing form field for a consulting issue. I agree, this is non-optimal.

Comment: @phil, I don't think you're going to find documentation that Chrome handles things differently, from what I have just tested, other browsers seem to behave in the same manner that you have described.

Comment: @phil, FYI getting the same results with `visibility: hidden;`